# dataannotations scaffoldcolumn?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I cant find wide resource about dataannotations with many examples.

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public int ReadCount { get; set; }
```

I want to show `ReadCount` with `DisplayForModel`, I dont want to use it in `EditorForModel`. How can I do this? Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to write a custom [`Object display template`](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Object.cshtml`) which will simply display the value even if you have set `[Scaffold(false)]` on the property:

```
@if (Model == null) 
{
    @ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText
}
else if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) 
{
    @ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText
}
else 
{
    foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) 
    {
        if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) 
        {
            @Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)
        }
        else 
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(prop.GetDisplayName())) 
            {
                <div class="display-label">@prop.GetDisplayName()</div>
            }
            <div class="display-field">@Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)</div>
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the only difference with the default display template that I have made is in the foreach selector where I have removed the `pm.ShowForDisplay` condition.

Now when you have the following property:

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public int ReadCount { get; set; }
```

it will be displayed with DisplayForModel and not displayed with EditorForModel.